# Can I bring two values from a single row into a Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot

I am trying to get two values from rows in a table into a single row in a pivot table.

myTable has the following rows

| ID1 | ID2 | Item | Value | SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | Item 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 11 | 22 | Item 2 | 100 | 100 |
| 11 | 22 | Item 3 | 49 | 55 |
| 12 | 22 | Item 1 | 16 | 15 |
| 12 | 22 | Item 2 | 99 | 100 |
| 12 | 22 | Item 3 | 15 | 15 |

I have tried using this

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [ID1],
           [ID2],
           [Item],     
           [Value],
           [SP]
  
    FROM [dbo].[tblDetails]
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(MAX([Value]) FOR [Item] IN([Item1],
                                                  [Item2],
                                                  [Item3]])                                     
                                                   ) AS PivotTable
```

Without the SP it gives me the rows as expected.

| ID1 | ID2 | Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 10 | 100 | 49 |
| 12 | 22 | 16 | 99 | 15 |

What I would like is:

| ID1 | ID2 | Item 1 | Item 1 SP | Item 2 | Item 2 SP | Item 3 | Item 3 SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 100 | 49 | 55 |
| 12 | 22 | 16 | 15 | 99 | 100 | 15 | 15 |

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately `PIVOT` doesn't allow rotating multiple columns like you want, so you have a few options to get this done. The easiest being using an aggregate function along with a `CASE` expression.

```
if object_id('tblDetails') is not null
    drop table tblDetails

CREATE TABLE tblDetails
    ([ID1] int, [ID2] int, [Item] varchar(6), [Value] int, [SP] int)
;
    
INSERT INTO tblDetails
    ([ID1], [ID2], [Item], [Value], [SP])
VALUES
    (11, 22, 'Item 1', 10, 10),
    (11, 22, 'Item 2', 100, 100),
    (11, 22, 'Item 3', 49, 55),
    (12, 22, 'Item 1', 16, 15),
    (12, 22, 'Item 2', 99, 100),
    (12, 22, 'Item 3', 15, 15)
;


select 
    ID1,
    ID2,
    Item1 = max(case when Item = 'Item 1' then Value end),
    Item1SP = max(case when Item = 'Item 1' then SP end),
    Item2 = max(case when Item = 'Item 2' then Value end),
    Item2SP = max(case when Item = 'Item 2' then SP end),
    Item3 = max(case when Item = 'Item 3' then Value end),
    Item3SP = max(case when Item = 'Item 3' then SP end)
from tblDetails
group by ID1, ID2
```

This gives the result:

| ID1 | ID2 | Item1 | Item1SP | Item2 | Item2SP | Item3 | Item3SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 100 | 49 | 55 |
| 12 | 22 | 16 | 15 | 99 | 100 | 15 | 15 |

By using the `CASE` expression along with the aggregate you can convert multiple row values into columns.

If you want to use `PIVOT` to accomplish this, then you'd need to first `UNPIVOT` the two columns `Value` and `SP`, then apply the `PIVOT` function to that result. The query would look a little like this:

```
select 
    ID1, 
    ID2,
    Item1_value, Item1_SP, 
    Item2_value, Item2_SP, 
    Item3_value, Item3_SP
from 
(
    select ID1, 
        ID2, 
        new_col = concat(replace(Item, ' ', ''), '_', d.col), 
        d.val
    from tblDetails t
    cross apply 
    (
        select 'value', value union all
        select 'SP', SP
    ) d (col, val)
) un
pivot
(
    max(val)
    for new_col in (Item1_value, Item1_SP, Item2_value, Item2_SP, Item3_value, Item3_SP)
) piv;
```

Which gives the exact same result:

| ID1 | ID2 | Item1_value | Item1_SP | Item2_value | Item2_SP | Item3_value | Item3_SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 100 | 49 | 55 |
| 12 | 22 | 16 | 15 | 99 | 100 | 15 | 15 |

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result by using two CTEs to PIVOT the source table on each column then joining the two CTEs to create a single result set.

**NOTE:** This only works when you have one row per `ID1 - ID2 - Item *N*` group, for example, if you have rows like below:

| ID1 | ID2 | Item | Value | SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | Item 1 | 100 | 25 |
| 11 | 22 | Item 1 | 90 | 50 |

These will return 100 for the **Item 1** column and 50 for the **Item 1 SP** column when the CTEs are joined because the PIVOT is using MAX for both columns. If this scenario is not going to occur, or if this behaviour is what you're after then this solution will work.

See this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3a9e6738639814e292e89651a3d9147c) for a working example of the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE DataTbl
(
    ID1 INT,
    ID2 INT,
    Item VARCHAR(25),
    VALUE INT,
    SP INT
)

INSERT INTO DataTbl (ID1, ID2, Item, Value, SP)
VALUES
(11, 22, 'Item 1', 10, 10),
(11, 22, 'Item 2', 100, 100),
(11, 22, 'Item 3', 49, 55),
(12, 22, 'Item 1', 16, 15),
(12, 22, 'Item 2', 99, 100),
(12, 22, 'Item 3', 15, 15)

;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT ID1
  , ID2
  , p1.[Item 1]
  , p1.[Item 2]
  , p1.[Item 3]
FROM
(
    SELECT [ID1],
        [ID2],
        [Item],     
        [Value]
    FROM DataTbl
) source
PIVOT ( MAX([Value]) FOR [Item] IN ([Item 1], [Item 2], [Item 3]) ) p1
), CTE2 AS 
(
SELECT ID1
  , ID2
  , p2.[Item 1] AS [Item 1 SP]
  , p2.[Item 2] AS [Item 2 SP]
  , p2.[Item 3] AS [Item 3 SP]
FROM
(
    SELECT [ID1],
        [ID2],
        [Item],     
        [SP]
    FROM DataTbl
) source
PIVOT ( MAX([SP]) FOR [Item] IN ([Item 1], [Item 2], [Item 3]) ) p2
)

SELECT p1.ID1
  , p1.ID2
  , p1.[Item 1]
  , p2.[Item 1 SP]
  , p1.[Item 2]
  , p2.[Item 2 SP]
  , p1.[Item 3]
  , p2.[Item 3 SP]
FROM CTE p1
INNER JOIN CTE2 p2 ON p2.ID1 = p1.ID1 AND p2.ID2 = p1.ID2
```

Result:

| ID1 | ID2 | Item 1 | Item 1 SP | Item 2 | Item 2 SP | Item 3 | Item 3 SP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 22 | 10 | 10 | 100 | 100 | 49 | 55 |
| 12 | 22 | 16 | 15 | 99 | 100 | 15 | 15 |

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  I tried a couple and they both did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Is there any advantage in performance of a particular solution?